# How to skip next steps if a condition is fulfilled in a feature file using karate

Tags: dsl, karate

My feature file looks somthing like this :

```
#Subscribe to an API

Given url applicationURL

And path 'subscriptions'

And header Authorization = subscribeToken

And request {'tier': 'Gold','apiIdentifier': '#(APIIDStr)','applicationId': '#(applicationId)'}

When method post

Then status 201

* def subscriptionId = response.subscriptionId

* print 'subscriptionID is ', subscriptionId 

* def status = response.status

* print 'subscribed with status ', status , ' and subscriptionID ' , subscriptionId

#* eval if (response.status == 'ON_HOLD') karate.call('BPSWorkflow.feature')

Given url applicationURL + '/applications/generate-keys?'

And param applicationId = applicationId

And header Authorization = subscribeToken

And request {"validityTime": "3600","keyType": "PRODUCTION","accessAllowDomains": ["ALL"]}

When method post

Then status 200

* def accessTokenforInvokation = 'Bearer '+ response.token.accessToken

* print 'accessTokenforInvokation is ', accessTokenforInvokation
```

I want to skip every step  after "#* eval if (response.status == 'ON_HOLD') karate.call('BPSWorkflow.feature')"  status is 'ON_HOLD'.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an experimental API you can use `karate.abort()` - here is the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#karateabort

This will be made more obvious and documented better in the next release.

```
* eval if (response.status == 'ON_HOLD') { karate.call('BPSWorkflow.feature'); karate.abort() }
```

Comment: Worked !! Thanks Peter :-)